# DataTable to Combobox - SelectedValue not being set in UI, two values returned

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

I know this is an almost persistent issue cropping up with `SelectedItem` with regards to databound `ComboBox` elements, but I'm also now struggling with this issue.

XAML:

```xml
<ComboBox x:Name="Price_List" BorderBrush="Gainsboro" Margin="5"  Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Background="{x:Null}"/>
```

Code-Behind:

```vb
Using Sql As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(ConnStr)
    Sql.Open()

    Using sqlcmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand(SQLQuery, Sql)

        Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter
        Dim DS As New DataSet
        Dim DT As New DataTable

        With DT.Columns
            .Add("price_list")
            .Add("description")
        End With

        With Price_List
            .ItemsSource = DT.DefaultView
            .DisplayMemberPath = "description"
            .SelectedValuePath = "price_list"
        End With

        DA.SelectCommand = sqlcmd
        DA.Fill(DT)
    End Using
End Using
```

`SelectedValue` is sort of working, as evidenced by a `Debug.Print` of the value in the `SelectionChanged`, but it is returning two values (one `NULL`) on each change - why would this be?

Obviously in this regard, the `SelectedValue` is always going to be different to the `DisplayMember`, so how do I force WPF to display it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you move it back insert some breakpoints in Main_Tabs_SelectionChanged and ensure the code is only executing once.

see https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/22e16180-914b-4b07-939e-b17ce692cf11/tab-control-selectionchanged-event-fires-a-combos-selectionchanged-event-fires?forum=wpf

Comment: Yep, this solved it. Added `e.handled = True` to the `SelectionChanged` event. Now I need to go look into Bubbling Up to work out whether I should be doing things differently all over the place...